# How to fix CI .htaccess inside wordpress directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i'm setting up a new codeigniter project inside wordpress directory, in the
localhost it works perfectly, but when i upload it to hosting it display 404 error page.

ex: http://xxxxxx.com/portal/login

output : The page you requested was not found.

.htaccess in root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

CI's .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /portal
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

note: our hosting by godaddy

Comment: are you loading CI or WP first?  I'm not sure about V3 but CIv2 you have to lode WordPress first, both libraries have functions like get_url, but CI has them wrapped in function_exists.

Comment: `htaccess in root directory` is all messed up, the `[L]` flag stands for the last rewrite rule, so anything that matches it that's the end of HTACCESS for it.  For example this `^ - [L]` will probably terminate any rules following it.  Because the `^` matches the start of any line and the `-` means no change basically and the `[L]` means last rule.

Comment: In general you would have the WP htaccess, and then in your CI folder (assuming its in HTACESS) it would have it's own separate file.  The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means if it's not a real directory, and your CI folder is a real directory, so the WP rewrite wont matter.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i use v3 , i think that in v2 can work without problem but i won't back to old version :)

Comment: Other then that, make sure your permissions are correct. `localhost it works perfectly, but when i upload it to hosting it display 404 error page.` this is exactly what can happen if you upload as root on a C-Panel server (or any server really).  No access to the files mean they wont be found.  Besides that maybe casings, windows is classless linux is case sensitive.

Comment: Yea we have a 6 year old site that is based on WP/CI ( and other stuff).

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i changed permissions controller it's work but the controller can't call the view, page show as empty

Comment: I would change all the permissions in your CI folder to be (what is it 0655 or 0755 or something), recursively.  `chmod -R 755 'path to CI'`  The PHP user must have the ability to read and execute PHP files.  Or you may be able to `chown` change the owner of them.  Or probably do both, as you may need write permissions for things like logging etc..

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix doesn't work :(